# Why do Ruby setter methods behave like assignment expressions?

Tags: ruby, methods, setter

I have a `price=` method inside a `Ticket` class, which sets a price only if it has at most two values after the decimal point:-

```
def price=(price)
    if (price*100).to_i == price*100
          @price = price
    else
          "The price format is off!"
    end
end
```

Now, when I add the code `puts price=(50.75543)`, I'm getting `50.75543` as the output. There are two questions which come to my mind:-

1. Why does the code even work? The method call isn't valid as such (I tried the same with the method name `set_price` instead of `price=` and it throws an error), as I haven't even created an instance of the `Ticket` class. It's almost as if the `price=` method is being treated as a variable assignment.
2. Even if the code is `puts t.price=(50.75543)`, where `t` is an instance of the `Ticket` class, the output is `50.75543`. Why is this so? How do I get it to output "The price format is off!"?

Comment: Close enough to be a duplicate but some clarification: (1) `puts price=(50.75543)` is just another way of saying `price = 50.75543; puts price`, your `price=` method is not used, you're just creating a local variable. (2) See the duplicate for why setters behave this way, if you want other behavior then you're going to have raise an exception.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand now! :) And it was rather dumb of me to not realize I was actually creating a local variable.